# Is there is a way to force highcharts to space columns equally spaces on datetime x-axis

Tags: highcharts

I have a service which has concept of billing cycles, each billing can have a different start date, so for example 21 Sep, 21 Oct, 22 Nov, 15 Dec, etc.

I am showing each billing cycle as column bar on the datetime x-axis, but problem is sometimes when two billing cycles has closer start date, bars overlaps with each other.

Is there a way to show these bars equally spaced on the datetime x-axis using highcharts, so bars don't overlaps.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to achieve this that I'm aware of.

1 - Use [xAxis categories](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.categories).  Create the xAxis categories array so that it has a 1:1 correspondence with your data series array.

See this js fiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/looshi/7tyu8ssp/5/

The data points will be evenly spaced visually, even though the dates are not evenly spaced in time.

```
    $(function () {
        $('#container').highcharts({

            xAxis: {
                categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
            },

            series: [{
                data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5], 
type: 'column'
            }]
        });
    });
```

2 - The other option is to upgrade to the highstock.js library -- and set the [xAxis 'ordinal' property](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.ordinal) to true.     Highstock is an additional set of features built on top of Highcharts.

Comment: thanks for quick reply!

Thanks for quick reply!

I know about categories, but problem is user can see data in different timescale like Year, Month, Day view and we show tooltip on column hover. So suppose if user is looking at data in Day view, labels would be - 12am, 1, 2,..... 12pm......11, but when user hovers on the bar, it displays the date also, so like this - *1AM Tuesday, 24th November 2015*

Comment: Have you tried the highstock upgrade features?  http://jsfiddle.net/looshi/kp1cwL9a/   Using the 'ordinal: true' property should work.

Comment: @SatyaNarayanPatidar You could use label and tooltip format/formatter to set up what will be displayed. API: [label.format](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.labels.format), [label.formatter](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#xAxis.labels.formatter), [tooltip.formatter](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#tooltip.formatter)